# Storing an events calendar using NSUserDefaults or CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, calendar

So I have an app which upon launch imports a user's specific calendar and displays all events related to it. I use NSPredicate to sort them and store the events in an array.

I would like to be able to store this array upon each launch of the app, then in another method i hope to recall it and subtract it from the same calendar events at a later time. The idea being that only the changed items will remain.

I have tried using NSUserDefaults to store the array which is about 70 items long but i get an error : Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')

I have tried converting the array to NSData using NSKeyedArchiver but that causes a crash aswell: exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EKEvent encodeWithCoder:]

Any suggestions on how I can store and recall my events array. The reason i mention coreData in the title is i fear some of you will tell me to use that which is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is generally ok, but you're falling over at actually saving because you can't directly save an `EKEvent` (it isn't permissible in user defaults and it doesn't implement `NSCoding`).

You need to extract the parts, such as the `eventIdentifier`, from each `EKEvent` and store them in another object that you can add to user defaults (like a dictionary) or that you can archive (so it and its contents need to conform to `NSCoding`).

When you reload the data you would then compare each element of data you saved instead of comparing the whole `EKEvent`s (not clear how you were doing the comparison anyway).

Comment: So that sounds great, of course I don't need all the info on the event, just the ID. I was then going to subtract the array I've stored of events 10 days ago let's say using removeObjectsInArray and what remains should be the new events only. Hopefully